# Flutter WebRtc : Remote Screen is always black

Tags: android, flutter, web, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I'm using flutter webrtc to make a streaming application, it has a web application that works perfectly when streaming, but on flutter mobile application the remote screen is always black although there is no error showing on the nodejs socketio server or the flutter logs.

here is the code of the watcher (reciever) Screen:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';
import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:mena/core/main_cubit/main_cubit.dart';
import 'package:mena/models/api_model/home_section_model.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/create_live/cubit/create_live_cubit.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/live_screens/live_cubit/live_cubit.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/start_live/cubit/start_live_cubit.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/start_live/widget/comments_live_list.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/start_live/widget/header_live_screen.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/start_live/widget/live_message_inputfield.dart';
import 'package:mena/modules/start_live/widget/paused_live.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';

import '../../core/constants/constants.dart';
import '../../core/functions/main_funcs.dart';

class WatcherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WatcherScreen(
      {Key? key, this.goal, this.title, this.topic, this.remoteRoomId})
      : super(key: key);

  final String? title;
  final String? goal;
  final String? topic;
  final String? remoteRoomId;

  @override
  State<WatcherScreen> createState() => _WatcherScreenState();
}

class _WatcherScreenState extends State<WatcherScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  MediaStream? _localStream;
  MediaStream? _remoteStream;

  late final AnimationController animationController;

  final _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  final RTCVideoRenderer _remoteVideoRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  bool _inCalling = false;
  bool _isTorchOn = false;
  MediaRecorder? _mediaRecorder;
  int count = 5;
  bool get _isRec => _mediaRecorder != null;

  List<MediaDeviceInfo>? _mediaDevicesList;
  RTCPeerConnection? _peerConnection;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _remoteVideoRenderer.initialize();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 16), (_) {
      _remoteVideoRenderer.renderVideo;
    });
    super.initState();
    MainCubit mainCubit = MainCubit.get(context);
    LiveCubit liveCubit = LiveCubit.get(context);
    String? roomId = widget.remoteRoomId;
    Socket socket = mainCubit.socket;
    socket.onAny((event, data) => logg('anyyy ${event}    ${data}'));
    socket.on('message', (data) {
      switch (jsonDecode(data)['type']) {
        case 'join':
          handleJoin(jsonDecode(data), mainCubit);
          break;
        case 'offer':
          handleOffer(jsonDecode(data), mainCubit);
          break;
        case 'answer':
          handleAnswer(jsonDecode(data));
          break;
        case 'candidate':
          handleCandidate(jsonDecode(data));
          break;
        case 'checkMeetingResult':
          if (jsonDecode(data)['result']) {
            _makeCall(mainCubit, roomId);
          }
          break;
      }
      // StartLiveCubit pros = StartLiveCubit.get(context);
      // pros.getProviders();
    });
    mainCubit.sendMessage({
      'type': 'checkMeeting',
      'username': 'ZainTest',
      'meetingId': roomId,
      'moderator': false,
      'authMode': 'disabled',
      'moderatorRights': 'disabled',
      'watch': true,
      'micMuted': false,
      'videoMuted': false,
    });

    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);

    animationController.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 1500);

    animationController.forward();
  }

  handleAnswer(data) {
    logg('handleAnswer ssssssssss ${data.fromSocketId}');
    var currentConnection = connections[data.fromSocketId];
    if (currentConnection) {
      currentConnection.setRemoteDescription(data.answer);
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
    "iceServers": [
      {
        "url": "stun:3.28.124.112:3478",
      },
      {
        "url": "turn:3.28.124.112:3478",
        "username": "ubuntu",
        "credential": "\$#@ubuntu\$#@",
      }
    ],
  };
  final Map<String, dynamic> offerSdpConstraints = {
    "mandatory": {
      "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
      "OfferToReceiveVideo": true,
    },
    "optional": [],
  };

  List<UserName> usernames = [];
  List<String> eventss = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> connections = {};
  handleJoin(data, MainCubit mainCubit) async {
    Socket socket = mainCubit.socket;
    logg('handleeeeeeeeeeeeee joiiiiiiiiin');
    usernames[data.socketId].username = data.username;
    usernames[data.socketId].micMuted = data.micMuted;
    usernames[data.socketId].watch = data.watch;
    usernames[data.socketId].videoMuted = data.videoMuted;

    RTCPeerConnection connection = await createPeerConnection(configuration);

    connections[data.socketId] = connection;
    setupListeners(connection, data.socketId, data.uuid, data.watch, mainCubit);
    connection.createOffer({'offerToReceiveVideo': true}).then((offer) {
      return connection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then((value) => {
          mainCubit.sendMessage({
            'type': 'offer',
            'sdp': connection.getLocalDescription(),
            'username': "Zain",
            'fromSocketId': socket.id,
            'toSocketId': data.socketId,
            'uuid': "234234234",
            'watch': true,
            'micMuted': false,
            'videoMuted': false,
          })
        });
  }

  setupListeners(
      connection, socketId, opponentUuid, watch, MainCubit mainCubit) {
    _localStream
        ?.getTracks()
        .forEach((track) => connection.addTrack(track, _localStream));
    Socket socket = mainCubit.socket;

    connection.onIceCandidate = (event) {
      if (event.candidate != "") {
        logg('event.candidate ${event.candidate}');
        mainCubit.sendMessage({
          'type': 'candidate',
          'candidate': event.candidate,
          'sdpMid': event.sdpMid.toString(),
          'sdpMLineIndex': event.sdpMLineIndex.toString(),
          'fromSocketId': socket.id,
          'toSocketId': socketId,
        });
      }
    };
    connection.onTrack = (event) {
      _remoteStream = event.streams[0];
      _remoteVideoRenderer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      connection.onAddStream = (stream) {
        var tracks = _remoteStream?.getTracks();
        logg('the tracks are : ${tracks}');
        setState(() {});
      };

      List<MediaStreamTrack> videoTracks = event.streams[0].getVideoTracks();
      if (videoTracks.isNotEmpty) {
        logg('asdasdasdasdasda s  ' + videoTracks[0].toString());
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        logg('the trackssssssss are not empty');
      }
      setState(() {});
    };
    connection.getStats().then((stats) {
      for (StatsReport stat in stats) {
        // Check if the statistic is a candidate pair statistic.
        if (stats.isNotEmpty) {
          // Get the first candidate pair.

          for (var statss in stats) {
            logg("candidatePair.values  :   ${statss.type.toString()}");
          }

          // Check if the candidate pair is succeeded.

          // The STUN and TURN servers are working.
        } else {
          // Log that the STUN and TURN servers are not working.
          logg("The STUN and TURN servers are not working.");
        }
      }
      // if (stats['stunIceCandidatePairs'].isNotEmpty) {
      //   logg("The STUN and TURN servers are working.");
      // } else {
      //   logg("The STUN and TURN servers are not working.");
      // }
    });
  }

  handleCandidate(data) {
    var currentConnection = connections[data['fromSocketId']];
    if (data['candidate'] != null && currentConnection != null) {
      logg('check nulllllllllls :${data}');
      MainCubit mainCubit = MainCubit.get(context);
      logg('check nulllllllllls :${mainCubit.socket.id}');
      int candidateIndex;
      if (data['candidate']['sdpMLineIndex'] == null) {
        int candidateIndex = int.parse(data['sdpMLineIndex']);
        currentConnection.addCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(
            data['candidate'], data['sdpMid'], candidateIndex));
      } else {
        if (data['candidate']['sdpMLineIndex'] is String) {
          candidateIndex = int.parse(data['candidate']['sdpMLineIndex']);
        } else {
          candidateIndex = data['candidate']['sdpMLineIndex'];
        }
        currentConnection.addCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(
            data['candidate']['candidate'],
            data['candidate']['sdpMid'],
            candidateIndex));
      }
      // RTCIceConnectionState iceConnectionState =
      //     currentConnection.iceConnectionState;

      // if (iceConnectionState ==
      //     RTCIceConnectionState.RTCIceConnectionStateConnected) {
      //   logg('ice is connected');
      // } else {
      //   logg('ice is not connected');
      // }
    }
  }

  handleOffer(data, MainCubit mainCubit) async {
    logg('offer data is ${data['sdp']['type']}');
    logg('offer data is ${data}');

    //initialize a new connection
    RTCPeerConnection connection = await createPeerConnection(configuration);
    logg('cccc : ${configuration}');
    connections[data['fromSocketId']] = connection;

    connection.setRemoteDescription(
        RTCSessionDescription(data['sdp']['sdp'], data['sdp']['type']));

    setupListeners(connection, data['fromSocketId'], data['uuid'],
        data['watch'], mainCubit);

    connection.createAnswer().then((answer) {
      setDescriptionAndSendAnswer(answer, data['fromSocketId'], mainCubit);
    });
  }

  setDescriptionAndSendAnswer(answer, fromSocketId, MainCubit mainCubit) {
    connections[fromSocketId].setLocalDescription(answer);
    Socket socket = mainCubit.socket;
    logg('the answer : ${answer}');

    mainCubit.sendMessage({
      'type': 'answer',
      'answer': {'sdp': answer.sdp, 'type': answer.type},
      'fromSocketId': socket.id,
      'toSocketId': fromSocketId,
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    _remoteVideoRenderer.dispose();
    _localRenderer.dispose();
    _localStream?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void initRenderers() async {
    await _localRenderer.initialize();
    await _remoteVideoRenderer.initialize();
  }

  void _makeCall(MainCubit mainCubit, String? roomId) async {
    try {
      if (!_inCalling) {
        mainCubit.sendMessage({
          'type': 'join',
          'username': "ZainJoin",
          'meetingId': roomId,
          'moderator': false,
          'watch': true
        });
        setState(() {
          _inCalling = true;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  bool isFrontCamera = true;

  void switchCamera() async {
    if (_localStream != null) {
      Helper.switchCamera(_localStream!.getVideoTracks()[0]);
    }
  }

  void flipCamera() {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    StartLiveCubit startLiveCubit = StartLiveCubit.get(context);

    bool keyboardVisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    var mainCubit = MainCubit.get(context);
    User user = mainCubit.userInfoModel!.data.user;
    return _remoteVideoRenderer.renderVideo
        ? RTCVideoView(_remoteVideoRenderer,
            objectFit: RTCVideoViewObjectFit.RTCVideoViewObjectFitCover)
        : Center(child: Text(_remoteVideoRenderer.renderVideo.toString()));
  }
}

class UserName {
  UserName({
    this.username,
    this.micMuted,
    this.watch,
    this.videoMuted,
  });

  String? username;
  bool? micMuted;
  bool? videoMuted;
  bool? watch;
}
```

The things I made sure its working:
The remoteStream has a VideoTrack and its enabled and not muted
The offer and answer creation is working perfectly
The Stun and Turn servers are working perfeclty and thery are my creation
The Host and the Answerer are sending the candidate of type "candidate" and it's being recieved perfectly

The Expected result is when I'm streaming from web or another mobile device the stream video should show on the watcher screen

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `.getSettings()` on your received videoTrack to check the video dimensions. If it's corresponding with the screen size - sender's part and transport layer (ICE/TURN/STUN/Answer/Offer) are working well and the problem is in the display part. Otherwise - check your sender, if it's REALLY sending the right stream.
2. Check bitrate in `getStats` - if the media traffic is really arriving.
3. Try to make a screenshot from your received track and display it as an image:

```
   videoTrack.captureFrame().then((frame) {
       final screenshot = Image.memory(frame.asUint8List());
   });
```

this will help you to understand if the issue is in VideoRenderer

PS Note, that `.renderVideo` property doesn't REALLY checks if the renderer is rendering the video - it's just checking that it has textureId and srcObject, nothing more.